# How do I solve a XGBoost error "feature_names mismatch"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm working on using XGBoost to make predictions using the iris dataset. The model is trained but when I try to make a new prediction I get the following error: ValueError: feature_names mismatch.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

iris_df.rename(columns={'sepal length (cm)':'sepal_length'}, inplace=True)
iris_df.rename(columns={'sepal width (cm)':'sepal_width'},inplace=True)
iris_df.rename(columns={'petal length (cm)':'petal_length'},inplace=True)
iris_df.rename(columns={'petal width (cm)':'petal_width'}, inplace=True)

data = iris_df[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']]
target = iris_df[['targets']]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

import xgboost as xgb

train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)

param = {
    'max_depth':4,
    'eta':0.3,
    'objective': 'multi:softmax',
    'num_class': 3}
epochs = 10

model = xgb.train(param, train, epochs)

predictions = model.predict(test)
print(predictions)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

All the code above works, but making new predictions is throwing an error:

```
testArray=np.array([[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2]])

test_individual=xgb.DMatrix(testArray)

print(model.predict(test_individual))\
```

How do I make the new prediction work?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. Had to turn dataframe objects into arrays:

```
train = iris_df[['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width']].values
test = iris_df[['target']].values
```

Comment: why are you calling `iris_df[['target']].values` as test?

Answer (score 0):

Pass xgb.DMatrix both the data array, 'testArray', and a labels list for column labels:

```
test_individual = xgb.Dmatrix(testArray, label = X_train.columns)
```

Comment: Got the following error: "ValueError: ('Expecting 2 dimensional numpy.ndarray, got: ', (4,))"

Answer (score 0):

Pass xgb.DMatrix a one-dimensional array:

```
testArray = np.array([5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2])
```

Comment: Got the following error: "ValueError: ('Expecting 2 dimensional numpy.ndarray, got: ', (4,))"